# Overloaded Operator Function Failing

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here I wrote 2 overloaded operators:

```
stringb operator+(const stringb &a,const stringb &b)
{
    stringb temp;
    temp.len = a.len + b.len;
    temp.p=new char[(temp.len)+1];
    strcpy(temp.p, a.p);
    strcat(temp.p, b.p);
    return (temp);
}
stringb operator-(const stringb &a,const stringb &b)
{
    stringb temp;
    temp.len=a.len-b.len;
    temp.p=new char[temp.len+1];
    strcpy(temp.p,a.p);
    return (temp);
}
```

However, when I compile  the actual code, the whole code works except the part when I call  these operator, and I get garbage out put. What's wrong with my functions?

EDIT: Declaration of stringb class:

```
class stringb
{
    public:
        char *p;
int len;
public:
    stringb()
    {
    len=0;
    p=0;
    }
stringb(const char *s)
{
    len=strlen(s);
    p=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(p,s);

}
stringb(const stringb &s)
{
    len=s.len;//strlen(s);
    p=new char[len+1];
    strcpy(p,s.p);
}
~stringb()
{
    delete p;
}

friend int operator==(const stringb &a,const stringb &b);
friend stringb operator+(const stringb &a,const stringb &b);
friend stringb operator-(const stringb &a,const stringb &b);
friend void putstring(const stringb a);

};
```

Comment: Declaration of `stringb` please

Comment: WTH is `stringb`, could you show this please!

Comment: @P0W Provided declaration.

Comment: @g-makulik Provided declaration.

Comment: Just one thing to throw out their, what happens when you call strlen on a pointer that points to null? You have a default contractor that defaults your pointer to NULL. However, if the copy constructor is called it calls strlen on a pointer that points to null. This is going to crash your code as well. However, the correct answer is g-makulik below.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
~stringb()
{
    delete p; // <<<<<
}
```

This will be executed if `temp` goes out of scope in your operator definition.

To get your code working you need a proper implementation of the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)** in your `stringb` class. You may also have a look at this nice [IDE one sample](http://ideone.com/0EjAoQ), [P0W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870232/p0w) has setup from your code.

Comment: No! You'll need to implement proper rule of 3 in `stringb`

Comment: Here's a good explanation and example: [Wikipedia 'Rule of three'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

Comment: SO's contribution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @Anurupa_Dey See it [your](http://ideone.com/0EjAoQ) implementation and **Rule of Three**

Comment: @g-makulik You should add "rule of three" statement into your answer

Comment: @g-makulik I don't think the OP understands your answer. Maybe walking him through what would cause his code to crash and why? I would respond, but you're answer is correct. I just don't think he is familiar enough with the Rule of Three. Just a thought, great answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a reference:

```
stringb& operator+(const stringb &a, const stringb &b);
{
   stringb *temp = new stringb();
   temp->len = a.len + b.len;
   [...]
   return *(temp);
}
```

Comment: Did This: 
`stringb *temp = new stringb;
 temp->len = a.len - b.len;
 temp->p=new char[temp->len+1];
 strcpy(temp->p,a.p);
 return *(temp);`

Still crashes.

Comment: Seems the error is in the -operator implementation. + works just fine.

Comment: Well, what if b is longer? How about abs(a.len-b.len)?

Comment: still crashes even after using abs, while the + one works superfine!

Comment: Don't return a reference to memory allocated on the free store (heap).  After this function returns, there are no pointers to the resource it allocates.